# PostgreSQL: Getting result of a function in a single column in PostgreSQL

Tags: function, postgresql

Trying to display the result in the form of table with different columns, but getting all result in a single column.

--My Function

```
create or replace function test1()       
returns table ( "Fname" varchar(20),"Lname" varchar(20),"A-B" bigint,"C-D" bigint,
"E-F" bigint ) as    
$body$  
begin  
return query  
SELECT tb."Fname",tb."Lname",count(tb."City"='A-B' OR NULL) AS "A-B",  
   count(tb."City"='C-D' OR NULL) AS "C-D",  
   count(tb."City"='E-F' OR NULL) AS "E-F"  
FROM "Table1" tb    
WHERE  tb."City" in ('A-B','C-D','E-F')    
GROUP BY 1,2  
ORDER BY 1,2;    
end  
$body$  
language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In instead of

```
select test1()
```

do

```
select * from test1()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need no plgpsql for this. This is just a plain query.

But supposing you just want to test it: How do you *call* the function?

For table returning functions you do: `select * from f1();`.

For functions returning one value you do `select f1();`.